# How to resolve Memory Leaks in ASP.NET 4.0 web application contains ashx handlers?

Tags: architecture, .net, memory-management

My team has built a web corporate ERP application using ASP.NET 4.0 with Entity Framework,ASHX handlers and web pages(>20). The app has been built to accomodate more than 15000 users. But when the application is hosted on Test Enviroment, it throws Bad Gateway error when logged in users exceeds 600. The app contains 3 layer - Front End(ASPX pages), Entity Layer, DataAccess Layer(Classes).

Backend server is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Testing report says - Connection TimeOuts, Large amount of Memory Leaks and Unmanaged Codes.
We have tried our best to fix memory leaks by disposing the objects and classes,etc. Application doesn't contain minimal images.

But still the problem remains same. Even the server configuration of both Web and DB server is at very high end. 16 CPU and 4 GB RAM.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Are you using Caching? At a guess when you have 600 users then the servers are struggling to service the demands for data.

Comment: Is there anything to do with the new keyword? http://danielksmith.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/use-the-new-keyword-if-hiding-was-intended/

Comment: Have you run static code analysis (Fxcop, etc)? Are you sure your Dispose patterns are all correct? Do you have any user-written threading code? Threading errors are so common as to be almost a dead certainty.

Comment: You have 16 cores and *4gb of ram* in your web server?? That's a terribly misbalanced server.

Comment: WinDbg alone will tell you where those resources are going in under 5 minutes, only trouble is without pryor experience it will take you 1-2 days just to learn how to use it properly and understand what it's output is. Look at [Tess Fernandez's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) - Tons of great resources for troubleshooting resource usage problems and using WinDbg

Comment: How trustworthy is your Testing report?  Is it possible that you've been given red herrings with statements like "Large amount of memory leaks? and "unmanaged codes"?  I ask because in my experience people trying to be helpful by diagnosing early can actually completely (and inadvertently) misguide your investigation.  Are the timeouts between the browser and webserver, or server and DB?  Have you confirmed there actually ever were memory leaks?  What is meant by "Unmanaged codes"?

Comment: By "logged in users exceeds 600" do you mean 600 users have logged in at some point and have active sessions? Or do you mean 600 users hitting the server with requests simultaneously? If the latter, default IIS config is, iirc, 200 threads, so if the requests take on average more than 1/3 of a second to service, you will run out of threads, start queueing, and when the queue fills, get errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to take you some time and 'digging in' to get a handle on what is causing the issue. Without being there and with access to the code, all we can offer is things to investigate, such as:

- Use performance monitor to get a better picture of what exactly is going on. Do this on both your web and database servers. There are different counters that you want to use for ASP.NET and for SQL Server. A search for perfmon.exe, counters, ASP.NET and SQL Server should get you on the right path as to which counters to start with. Run through various scenarios and examine the numbers in detail: a single user on the site performing various actions, 10 users, 100, etc.
- Use SQL Server Profiler to get some insight into what is happening on the database side of things.
- Use WinDbg - Internet search will get you on the right path - will take some ramp-up if you're not familiar with it, but it's powerful.
- I've had great luck in the past using tools like Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler and Memory Profiler ([Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/)). The tools may cost a bit, but they have saved me **way** more than they cost in being able to quickly identify the 'low hanging fruit' issues. Disclosure - I'm not affiliated with Red Gate in any way.
- Do the problems in the test environment start exactly when the users exceed 600, or just generally at some number that varies but is over 600? If the problems always starts at the same number of users, that is a clue to look at what exactly happens when a new user logs in - are you loading a ton of data that isn't necessarily needed, etc. Actually, you should look into this even if the number of users where the problem starts varies, it just has a 'smell' if it always starts at exactly 600...
- Are you making heavy use of Session? Where is it stored?
- What is the required number of simultaneous users you need to support? You mention 15,000, are you load balancing across web servers? (This isn't necessarily related to fixing your problem, but something you may need to consider for your architecture)
- 4 GB of RAM is not very high end, especially for a database server. You likely need more, but this is not to say 'just throw RAM' at your problem, the above items should still be investigated.

Comment: +1 for WinDbg, though it's a steep learning curve, learning to use it is invaluable. With proper knowledge of how to use it, you can usually identify exactly what's using your resources with it in a couple minutes - then comes the even harder part of knowing how the memory allocation and GC actually works to know how to correct the problem.